# Value of coefficient in estimation of computational complexity of polynomial division algorithm 

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis

Do you know value of coefficient $C$ at $C*n*log(n)$ in $O(n*log(n))$ estimation of complexity of polynomial division algorithm?

It would be great if you give me links to paper with information about it.

**UPD.1** By complexity I meant arithmetic complexity

**UPD.2** Estimation $O(n*log(n))$ one can find in §8 of book Alfred V. Aho, J.E. Hopcroft, Jeffrey D. Ullman, The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms, Addison-Wesley Series in Computer Science and Information Processing (1974).

Comment: The constant C (and in fact the time complexity itself) is not well-defined unless you define the computational model.  Even with a specific computational model, the constant C is not well-defined in most cases because of the linear speedup property.

Comment: It would be great if you could give us links to sources which claim/prove $Cn\log n$ complexity for polynomial division, as then we might know what assumptions were going into that bound and might be able to work out what the implied constant is. 

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to point out that complexity is arithmetic complexity.

Example of estimation you can find in book in updated question.

Example of constant estimation you can find S. B. Gashkov, “Remarks on the fast multiplication of polynomials, and Fourier and Hartley transforms”, Diskr. Mat., 12:3 (2000), 124–153 ( http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dm&paperid=340&option_lang=eng ). Let $M(n)$ to be arithmetic complexity of polynomials multiplication. Then $M(n) \leq 27/2 * n * log_2 n + O(n*log_2*log_2 n)$.
